# confirm when change selected if iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe with class = "iframe" and navigation bar with 4 elements 3 of them contains 3 options below it each of them opens a specified url in iframe,
 and 4th element is to close the iframe after confirming message. 
what i want: if user select any subelement while iframe already loaded ask him first if he want to leave , if answer true allow him to load the selected sub element , if answer false do nothing.
this what i try:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function(){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to close?") == true) { 
      $('.iframe').hide();
    }else{
    }
  });
  $('.iframe').on('load', function(){
    $('.subElement').click(function(){
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?") == true) { 
      }else {
        $('.subElement').preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;
}
.nav ul li ul li{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul calss="main_ul">
    <li><a href="#">element1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="subElement" href="#">subElement1</a></li>
        <li><a class="subElement" href="#">subElement2</a></li>
        <li><a class="subElement" href="#">subElement3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">element2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="subElement" href="#">subElement1</a></li>
        <li><a class="subElement" href="#">subElement2</a></li>
        <li><a class="subElement" href="#">subElement3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">element3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="subElement" href="#">subElement1</a></li>
        <li><a class="subElement" href="#">subElement2</a></li>
        <li><a class="subElement" href="#">subElement3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a class="close" href="#">close iframe url</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br>
<iframe class= "iframe" src="http://stackoverflow.com"> width="300" height="200"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! This is what I changed to make it work:

```
$('.iframe').on('load', function(){
  $('.subElement').click(function(){
    if ($('.iframe').is(':visible')){
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?") == true) { 
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
  });
});
```

or a simpler version:

```
$('.iframe').on('load', function(){
  $('.subElement').click(function(){
    if ($('.iframe').is(':visible')){
        if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?")) { 
            return false;
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a simple check to see if the iframe is loaded rather than using jquery to create the function upon loading. Here is another way of doing as you described, but notice that the first if-statement checks if the iframe is visible and loaded. So if you may want to change this depending on if you want to display a message if the iframe is loaded, but hidden.

Hope this helps. :)

```
$('.subElement').click(function(){
    var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName('iframe');
  if(iframe[0].readyState == 'complete' && iframe[0].style.display != "none"){
    //If iframe is open:
     if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?")) { 
        $(this).preventDefault();
      }
  }else{
    //If Iframe is not open
  }
});
```